# How do I get the hosts from a specific section of an Ansible `hosts` file in a Jinja2 Template

Tags: ansible, jinja

I have a `hosts` file including the following contents

```
[elasticsearch_nodes]
host1 os=linux
host2 os=linux
host3 os=linux
```

In a `.j2` template I want to get the the list of `[elasticsearch_nodes]`

```
{{ some_ansible_magic_here }}

# should output "host1","host2","host3"
```

How do I do this?

I do have this as well to help with the quotes and the commas when I have the list.

```
{% for host in some_sort_of_ansible_magic_to_get_me_that_list_i_need %}
 "{{ host }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The magic you need is [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables), in particular the `groups` variable, [which is](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic)

> a dictionary/map with all the groups in inventory and each group has the list of hosts that belong to it.

Then you can use template [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) to format the list: use `map` with `regex_replace` to add the quotes to all list elements and then `join` them into the final result.

```
{{ groups['elasticsearch_nodes']|map('regex_replace', '(.*)', '"\\1"')|join(',') }}
```